# Why is the background image scrolling?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I'm trying to make this background image fit the width of the browser window without scrolling horizontally. I'm also running into issues with centering everything on the page because of this. Unfortunately this issue keeps occuring in my recent projects, and I've tried everything I can think of to solve it.

Is it something wrong with my code, the image sizes, am I missing something?

```css
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}


.main-nav {
 display: none;
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
 position: absolute;
 top: 70;
 left: 15;
 font-size: .5em;
}

.promo {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 99;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: .7em;
 text-align: center;
}


.welcome {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 background: 
 linear-gradient(#303030, transparent 90%),
 url('../imgs/camerabg.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -10px;
 padding: 200px;
} 

.welcome h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
}

.welcome a {
 text-decoration-style: underline;
 color: lightgrey;
 font-size: 2em;
 display: inline-block;
}

.welcome ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

.location {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 2px solid lightgrey;
 color: lightgrey;
}

.products {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 background: linear-gradient(#181818, transparent 90%),
 url('../imgs/oldcamera.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 150px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

 .products h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
 }

 .products a {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 2em;
 }

 /*===============================
    Intro
==============================*/

.intro1, .intro2 p {
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
}

.intro1, .intro2 span {
 font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Yantramanav" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesheet.css">
 <title>TITLE HERE</title>
</head>

<body>

<header>
<div class="promo">
 <p>BUY 1 GET 1 Free 1/2 OFF CLOCK FRAME COMBOS<br>
 *Offer Valid 5/1/18. May not be combined with another offer or promotion. While supplies last.*<p>
</div>

<div class="logo">
<h1> Name Here</h1>
</div>

<div class="main-nav">
 <ul>
  <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li>Blog</li></a>
  <a href="#"><li> Hire Us</li></a>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="welcome">
 <h1>Welcome To Our New Site</h1>
 <p>Let us help you with your best moments.</p>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Order Now</a></li>
 <li><a class="location" href="#">Find Our New Location</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>

<div class="intro1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
<span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</span>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to start using the magic of `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.welcome`. Your current width is 100% + padding.

Comment: @YoungSherlock : Remove the padding from the welcome class - then add top and bottom padding if you wish, here is an example: `.welcome {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', sans-serif;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    background: linear-gradient(#303030, transparent 90%), url(../imgs/camerabg.jpg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -10px;
    padding-top: 200px; }` and a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ey5zushh/

Comment: So, I added box-sizing: border-box to .welcome and the image still scrolls, but now it doesn't go the full width of the window.This unfortunately didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you update the question with the newest code you tried?